# Python class decorator only called once, instead of every time decorated class instantiated

Tags: python, class, decorator, instantiation, python-decorators

### What?

I am using a class decorator, to decorate another class.

### Why?

The purpose of the decorator is to set up some config (arbitrary data) that will be copied across to the decorated class.

### What's the problem?

I want the decorator `class A` to run every time I instantiate the decorated `class B`.

The output of the code clearly shows `class A` acting as a singleton, only being instantiated and called once, the first time the decorated class is instantiated.

I would prefer to use class decorators throughout, as they are easier to read and understand than function decorators. If there is a reason why a function decorator may be a better solution for this problem, then that is fair enough.

Thanks.

### Code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, description):
        print 'init A'
        self.description = description

    def __call__(self, decorated):
        print 'call A'
        for attr, val in vars(self).iteritems():
            setattr(decorated, attr, val)
        return decorated

@A('Arbitrary stuff')
class B(object):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print b.description
    c = B()
    print c.description
```

### Output

```
init A
call A
Arbitrary stuff
Arbitrary stuff
```

### Desired output

```
init A
call A
Arbitrary stuff
init A
call A
Arbitrary stuff
```

Comment: It's a class decorator. The class is only created once. If you want to decorate instances of that class, you'd need an instance decorator, if such a thing existed. You'll have to wrap the class's `__init__`.

Comment: Also, why not use simple inheritance?

Comment: I'm creating a DSL for content developers and want my 'template' (`class B` in this case) to be as declarative as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, putting in a `print('start')` before `if __name__` would prove that `init A` and `call A` are being invoked before you instantiate `B`. Why is that?

Converting the syntactic sugar that is the `@` into the function calls might help with understanding what's actually going on.

```
class B:
    pass

B = A('Arbitrary stuff').__call__(B)  # B with an attached attribute

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

It's now clear where `A.__init__` and `A.__call__` are invoked.

`A.__call__` returns the object passed to it, therefore, calling `B` later on will simply return an instance of `class B`.

`A.__call__` would need to return the object you want to invoke when calling `B` later on.